# Send parameters to web service

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

I have written a function to get a response from web service. But now I want to send parameters to a web service. How can I modify the code below to send parameters to another web service? I want to work with the below code, I am new to IOS and dont want to mess up since I have a working code.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
recordResults = FALSE;

NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<GetUserList xmlns=\"http://methodoor.com/checkupservice/\" />\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n"];
//NSLog(soapMessage);

_lbl_result.text = soapMessage;


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://servicing2.rotanet.com.tr/service.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://methodoor.com/checkupservice/GetUserList" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}

//[nameInput resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: [this link](http://methodoor.com/checkupservice/GetUserList) does not open ? Is it possible to get wsdl description for the GetUserList method and Parameters ?

Comment: well, I am just asking to learn how to do it. web service I made doesnt need a parameter. but I will modify my webservice to response to a parameter. I just want to know how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you are accessing SOAP web services. And you are already sending data in to your web service in SOAP message.

As this is a SOAP API, you only need to change the SOAP Action `[theRequest addValue: @"http://methodoor.com/checkupservice/GetUserList" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];` and SOAP message, which you can get from the WSDL or SVC file, to access another method of your web service.

For more info you can have a look at [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/) link. Hope this helps.